# LogicalTree VisualTree Issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I would like to know how add to VisualTree and add to LogicalTree work in details. I know the basics and I read few articles on the internet about the two but those article were mostly about differences between them. What I need is to know how they work or better said how AddVisualTree AddLogicalTree method work once I wish to have my custom control that derivates from FrameworkElement and that has collection of children.

Do I need to call both method on every child/UIElement inside my custom control?

Can I add a UIElement to logical tree but not to visual tree?

Does adding to logical tree automatically include adding to visual tree? If yes then I would only need to call one method instead of two.

How does WPF know what is parent of a child/UIElement once added to logical tree since the logical parent could be a nodes far away on higher level than child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, adding an element to the logical tree will affect the way the control is rendered (i.e., the Visual Tree).  And yes, you can add a lookless, templateless element to the logical tree such that its participation in the rendering is nil, but you would need a really good explanation to convince a senior developer that it was a good idea.

If you are writing a WPF Custom Control (as opposed to a User Control), you would establish the Logical Tree in the Control Template in the first instance; and the Visual Tree would be implicit based upon what your control inherited from and then what you added to your Control Template (such as an Adorner or Border).

You would climb a Visual Tree, for example, to reach the VirtualizingStackPanel (VSP) of a ListBox, but that's only if the natural behaviour of the VSP needed to be tweaked meet your requirements.  On the other hand, programmatically climbing down the Visual Tree to reach the Content Presenter should be unnecessary because it can be addressed in Xaml declaratively.  As a rule of thumb, if you found yourself having to programmatically climb or descend the Visual Tree a lot, then it could be a signal that your control needs to inherit from a different control or it could be a signal that your design has been misconceived.

Overall, when building a Custom Control, try to do as much as possible on both trees declaratively (i.e., in Xaml), and avoid the need for programmatically climbing and descending them.  The same goes for programmatically adding children (that can also be done declaratively with templates).

Comment: I still dont understand how can binding work if I only use AddVisualTree method since binding shall only work on elements that are in logical tree. Whats you mean to this?

Comment: You would use Xaml to add items declaratively, and the WPF plumbing does all of that automatically.  I think you might need to study how the Xaml parser builds the object graph?  People are not building controls by adding to the visual tree programmatically.

Comment: But is inside the InternalChildren.Add method both AddVisualChild and AddLogicalChild included?

Comment: When you add a logical child, its visual tree is implicit in the control template.  Plus the control may have properties that change the trees dynamically, like a ListBox.  But I'm starting to think you may have the wrong end of the stick.  Do you want to write a application targeted to an end-user that has custom controls?  Or do something else like modify the WPF plumbing?

Comment: Here is an example. I have a Panel and I have 10 children but I only need randomly choosen 4 kids. So I pick the 4 children randomly. Now I need to make them alive. Would it be enough to just call AddLogicalChild in MeasureOverride of the Panel? If AddLogical doesnt include AddVisualChild I would need to call AddVisualChild explictly. On those other 6 childs that I dont want I would need to call RemoveLogical then. Right?

Comment: No, none of that stuff. In a contemporary WPF approach you would create a container control and bind its items to a collection; and each item of the collection would have its Visibility property bound to a property in your ViewModel.  All of that is done in Xaml declaratively.  You may need to do some studying on WPF at this point.

Comment: What are you talking about? I am talking about adding to visualtrees but you seem talking about binding visibility? Read my question again please.

Comment: Good point!  Let's wait until the experts weigh in with their responses.  Hopefully it will clarify things and answer your questions.